# C++でOpenCVのプログラムをコンパイルできません

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

次のC++のプログラムをコンパイルできません. 原因を教えてください.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );

    cvNamedWindow( "scrot.png", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    cvShowImage( "scrot.png", img );

    cvReleaseImage( &img );

    cvDestroyWindow( "scrot.png" );

}
```

#### エラーメッセージ

```
reg++ -Wall -o "rei2-1" "rei2-1.cpp"（ディレクトリ: /home/pi/Desktop/C） /tmp/ccWxBQc9.o: 関数 main' 内: 
rei2-1.cpp:(.text+0x28): cvLoadImage' に対する定義されていない参照です
rei2-1.cpp:(.text+0x3c): cvNamedWindow' に対する定義されていない参照です
rei2-1.cpp:(.text+0x4c): cvShowImage' に対する定義されていない参照です
rei2-1.cpp:(.text+0x58): cvReleaseImage' に対する定義されていない参照です
rei2-1.cpp:(.text+0x60): cvDestroyWindow' に対する定義されていない参照です  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status コンパイル失敗 –
```

#### 追記

・Desktop版のRaspberry PiでGeanyを開き, そこにあるコンパイルのボタンを押しました.
・OpenCVのバージョンは3.4.1です.

Comment: リンクエラーが起こっているみたいですね、ライブラリの参照を見直す必要があるかもしれません。ビルド環境は何ですか？VisualStudioですか？

Comment: libopencv をリンクしていないためですね。

Comment: Raspberry Pi 3 Model BのGeanyです.

Comment: このURLの内容は役に立ちませんか？「http://www.cellstat.net/editor/」もしこれで解決したら手順を自己回答形式でまとめていただけると助かります。

Comment: [I cannot compile c++ program. - Raspberry Pi Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=222060&p=1362052)

Comment: @metropolis さん, そのURLは僕が投稿した質問です(^_^;)

Answer (score -1):

OpenCVの関数を呼び出そうとしている箇所で「定義が見つからない」とエラーになっているように見えますが、OpenCVのバージョンによって`Include`の記述が異なるようです。
もし`2.x`以降をお使いなら`include`記述の部分を

```
#include <opencv/cv.h> 
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
```

の様に`opencv/*`のサブディレクトリ名も含める必要があるようです。

参考:
http://hikopatchi.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/03/31/184937
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.4/include/opencv